# How can i apply @font-face in React without .css file

Tags: css, reactjs, import, font-face

I have generated "@font-face { font-family: 'RFDewiExpanded-Thin';font-weight: 100;
font-style: normal; src: ........}".
How can i apply it in React without external files?

Haven't any idea how to solve this problem.
Dynamic CCS import needs external file as i know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you can do this natively. However, if using a **CSS-in-JS** library it is possible to be able to do that and keep things all to one file. Examples are JSS, Emotion, Styled JSX etc

Is there a reason you are unable to import a separate `.css` file? You can do dynamic things in CSS with variables and CSS imports. One method I have used would recommend is **postcss-import**

Answer (score 0):

You can directly define the @font-face rule in your React component.

In the useEffect hook, a new FontFace object is created. It is then added to the `document.fonts` collection.
To clean up the font resources when the component unmounts, you can return a cleanup function from the useEffect hook.

**Example:**

```
    import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

    const MyComponent = () => {

        const elementRef = useRef(null);

        useEffect(() => {
            const fontFace = new FontFace(
                'RFDewiExpanded-Thin',
                'url(pathToYourFontFile.woff2)'
            );

            document.fonts.add(fontFace);

            fontFace.load()
                .then(() => {
                    if (elementRef.current) {
                        elementRef.current.style.fontFamily = 'RFDewiExpanded-Thin';
                        elementRef.current.style.fontWeight = 100;
                        elementRef.current.style.fontStyle = 'normal';
                    }
                });

            return () => {
                fontFace.loaded.then(() => {
                    document.fonts.remove(fontFace);
                });
            };
        }, []);

        return (
            <div ref={elementRef}>
                My Component Here
            </div>
        );
    };

    export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export function loadFont(fontStyle) {
  var newStyle = document.createElement('style');
  newStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fontStyle));
  document.body.appendChild(newStyle);
}

  const uploadFile = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];

    const fileName = file.name;
    const fileNameL = fileName.toLowerCase();
    const fontName = fileName.split('.')[0];
    const fileExtension = fileName.split('.')[1];

    let fontWeight = 'normal';
    let fontStyle = 'normal';

    if (fileNameL.includes('bold')) {
      if (fileNameL.includes('semibold')) {
        fontWeight = '600';
      } else {
        fontWeight = 'bold';
      }
    } else if (fileNameL.includes('medium')) {
      fontWeight = '500';
    } else if (fileNameL.includes('thin')) {
      fontWeight = '100';
    }

    if (fileNameL.includes('italic')) {
      fontStyle = 'italic';
    }

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      const fontData = event.target.result;
      const base64 = _arrayBufferToBase64(fontData, (base64data) => base64data);

      const fontCSS = `@font-face {
        font-family: '${fontName}';`enter code here`
        src: url('data:${fileExtension};base64,${base64}') format('${fileExtension}');
        font-weight: ${fontWeight};
        font-style: ${fontStyle};
      }`;
      const data = { css: fontCSS, fontName, fileName };

      loadFont(fontCSS);
      save(fontName, data);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

`@font-face` is an CSS property so you can you only when browser know that this is CSS code, below is the example that you can use `@font-face` or any other CSS property without `.css` file.

```
export default function myFunction() {
  const fontFamily = `
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'fontFamilyName';
      src: url('/path/to/fontname.woff2') format('woff2'),
           url('/path/to/fontname.woff') format('woff');
    }
  `;

  return (
    <div>
      <style>{fontFamily}</style>
      <p style={{ fontFamily: 'fontFamilyName' }}>This text is styled with custom font family</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```